# Solution for countdown timer for my swing game. (cardlayout)

Tags: java, swing, events, timer, layout-manager

I'm making a swing maze game, and I use the cardlayout to go from panel to panel in my game(**Main Menu --> Choose Difficulty Screen --> Game Screen**).

 I've got my game and menu set up and now I'm trying to add a countdown clock to let the user knows that he has X amount of seconds left before game over.

I made a countdowntimer and it works perfectly for 1 map(1 panel), but when I try to use it for other panels (my other 2 maps). It gets really buggy. the timer doesn't stop doing its actions after it reaches 0 ( an option pane, and a beep sound).
So The TimerEvent and TimerClass class do work when I link them to my GUI(other gui that I posted here but way to many lines to post here). But it gets all buggy when I try to add more timer to other panels (for different levels between my game).
Sorry for my bad english, and thank you veryyy much!!

sincerely, a beginner programmer

### MENU Class (very short and basic version which I made for you to test):

```
package labyrinthproject.View;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Card {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel();
    JButton gopanel1 = new JButton("go panel1");
    JButton gopanel2 = new JButton("go panel2");
    final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    panelCont.setLayout(cl);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panelCont);
    frame.pack();

    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel1.add(gopanel1);
    panel1.add(gopanel2);
    gopanel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.show(panelCont, "2");
        }
    });
    gopanel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.show(panelCont, "3");
        }
    });
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.black);
    panel2.add(timerLabel)
    panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    panel3.setBackground(Color.blue);

    panelCont.add(panel1, "1");
    panelCont.add(panel2, "2");
    panelCont.add(panel3, "3");
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

### My timerEvent class (changed a little to look like it suited for the above class)

```
public class TimerEvent implements ActionListener {
static TimerEvent e = new TimerEvent();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int count = 60;
        Card.timerLabel.setText("Time: " + count);

        TimerClass tc = new TimerClass(count);
        Card.timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
        Card.timer.start();
    }
}
```

### My TimerClass:

```
public class TimerClass implements ActionListener {

int counter;

public TimerClass(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent tc) {
    counter--;

    if (counter >= 1) {
        Card.timerLabel.setText("Time:" + counter);
    } else {
        Card.timer.stop();
        Card.timerLabel.setText("Done");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainMenu.panelCont, "Time expired, game over");
        Card.cl.show(MainMenu.panelCont, "2");
        Card.timer.stop();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
int counter;
for (int j = 0 ; j >=counter ; j++) {
   Card.timerLabel.setText("Time:" + counter);
   delayer (1000);
}

private static void delayer (long milliseconds)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep (1000);
    }

    catch (InterruptedException ex){
    }
}
```

Comment: I read on the webz that i had to be carefull using threads, and better use the swing timer :s But i'll try yours, and if it works..well then it works. i'll let you know